# How to override a standard class or how to actually refresh ResourceBundle?

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem that is driving me mad and I hope you can help me.

**The Scenario**

I'm working on Java application that uses a external Library (jar I cannot modify) that uses a `ResourceBundle` to read one property. The `ResourceBundle` is assigned to an static variable inside one class from the library. I want to be able to change that property dynamically so after a lot of tries I have implemented that property list with a `ListResourceBundle` as it's the easiest way to change the values on runtime.

The Application has two threads:
- Main thread: that is the first one to load for first time the `ResourceBundle` through the external library.
- Child Thread: which also uses the external library and the class that loads the `ResourceBundle`.

**The Problem**

When I change the `ListResourceBundle` properties values and call `ResourceBundle.clearCache()` it works and the external library takes the new value.

The problem comes when I try to do the same thing from the thread, I change the value, `clearCache()`, but it uses the last value from Main Thread, not the specified trough the child Thread. In fact, if I get the value for the property from the Tread it returns the **new value**, athough the external class uses the **old one**.

**What I tried**

- I have trying using `clearCache` specifing the Class Loader, but the `ListResourceBundle` is being loaded throw AppClassLoader, which class loader is `null`, so I can not force to `clearCache` through it.
- I have tried using a `ResourceBundleControl` to disable cache at the very start of the application but it doesn't work:

```java
public long getTimeToLive(String baseName, Locale locale) {
    return TTL_DONT_CACHE;
}
```

**Alternatives**

- Am I missing something to `clearCache` from the child thread? Is there anyway to totally disable the `ResourceBundle` cache? I'm only using one property.
- Is it possible in Java, to redirect a standard class usage (`java.util.ResourceBundle`) to a custom one? I haven't find anything about this, and I think it should not be difficult. That way I could force the external library to read the property from my own, not cached, and not `ResourceBundle` based class.

Comment: There was a "Hi all" at the beggining but I don't know where it is... I'm trying to edit it but it doesn't change...

Comment: 1) Is the library you are referring to publicly available? And if yes, what class in it? 2) Is the field the `ResourceBundle` is stored in `final` (the field in the library)? 2) What does your current code (the one that does not work in a multi-threaded environment) look like?